# How to find multiple possible path using Dijkstra's algorithm in iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am finding path between two nodes using Dijkstra's algorithm.

I have successfully founded shortest path between two nodes but now i want all possible path between two node for some specific task.

I am using [Dijkstra's algorithm for now](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/dijkstra-algorithm-swift/). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class will give you all possible routs between two nodes. Just Copy this class from here and at bottom i am providing how to use this algorithm.

```
class Graph {

private var v : Int
private var adjList : [[Int]] = []
private var allPossiblePath : [[Int]] = []
init(vertices : Int)
{
    v = vertices
    initAdjList()
}
private func initAdjList()
{
    adjList = [[Int]](repeating: [0], count: v)
    for i in 0..<v
    {
        adjList[i] = []
    }
}

public func addEdge(u : Int,v : Int)
{
    adjList[u].append(v)
}

public func printAllPaths(s : Int,d : Int)
{
    var isVisited = [Bool](repeating: (0 != 0),count: v)
    var pathList = [Int]()
    pathList.append(s)
    printAllPathsUtil(u: s, d: d, isVisited:&isVisited, localPathList:&pathList)
}

private func printAllPathsUtil(u: Int, d: Int, isVisited: inout [Bool], localPathList: inout [Int])
{
    if u == d
    {
        if (localPathList.count < 55)
        {
            allPossiblePath.append(localPathList)
            //print(localPathList)
        }
        return
    }
    isVisited[u] = true
    for i in adjList[u]
    {
        if !isVisited[i]
        {
            localPathList.append(i)
            //print(i)
            printAllPathsUtil(u: i, d: d, isVisited:&isVisited, localPathList:&localPathList)
            localPathList.removeAll{$0 == i}
        }
    }
    isVisited[u] = false
}
public func getAllPossiblePath() -> [[Int]]
{
    return allPossiblePath
}}
```

Here is code how to use it.

```
 let g = Graph(vertices: data_Rout.count)
    
  for routData in data_Rout
  {
      g.addEdge(u: routData.route_source_id, v: routData.route_destination_id)
  }
 g.printAllPaths(s: fetchSingleMyNodeFromList(station_code: "\(routsAndFilterDepartStation!.station_code)")!.station_id,d: fetchSingleMyNodeFromList(station_code: "\(routsAndFilterDestinationStation!.station_code)")!.station_id)
 let allPossiblePaths = g.getAllPossiblePath()
```

Comment: Hi @hardik can you share sample code of finding the shortest path

Comment: can you share sample code via github please

Comment: @Codecracker by using this only you will get all type of path you just find least number of station path from all possible path than you have the shortest path.

Comment: @Codecracker you can also use this for shortest path finding https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/dijkstra-algorithm-swift/